# Regex that flags full name + optional middle names with NO symbols

Tags: regex

I'm trying to flag `FirstName Multiple MiddleNames LastName` using Regex however with no symbols (brackets, commas, anything).

**Successful:**

- John James Doe
- James John Doe Kedron
- John Doe

**Invalid (as a whole, not partially correct):**

- John James, Doe
- (James) John Doe Kedron

I have `\^.+ .+\` which works great for spacing/picking up potentially multiple middle names, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to exclude any characters for the whole set.

I have tried `\^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+\` however this doesn't include future phrases.

I have tried `\^(\S+)\s+(.*\b)\s+(\S+)$\` which is great for phrasing but does not exclude symbols. I need to perhaps use `[a-zA-Z]` in here somewhere.

Comment: May be this: `\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)+\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For English only names you can use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ alpha chars
- `(?:` - non-capturing group start
- `\s` - a single space
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ alpha chars
- `)+` - non-capturing group end, repeated 1+ times
- `$` - anchor at end of string

If you want to support international names with marks (accents etc), such as **Jörg Müller**, or **橋本明美**, but exclude special chars, use this:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+(?:\p{Zs}[\p{L}\p{M}]+)+$/u
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `[\p{L}\p{M}]+` - letters in all languages

  - `\p{L}` - denotes a letter char in any language
  - `\p{M}` - denotes a mark (accent etc)
- `(?:` - non-capturing group start
- `\p{Zs}` - denotes a single space char, such as regular space   and Japanese space char
- `[\p{L}\p{M}]+` - letters in all languages
- `)+` - non-capturing group end, repeated 1+ times
- `$` - anchor at end of string
- add the `u` flag for Unicode support

See docs on Unicode regex: https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Comment: @PoulBak: It's not specified, and this is not JavaScript specific. Unicode regex is supported by Java, XML and the .NET framework. Perl supports Unicode starting with version 5.6. PCRE can optionally be compiled with Unicode support. Ruby supports Unicode escapes and properties in regular expressions starting with version 1.9.